# Не могу задеплоить на Cloudflare Pages. Требует модуль Globby

Tags: node.js, npm, cloudflare, yarn

Этот модуль я установил, последнюю версию, но при деплое все время выходит ошибка, просит более позднюю версию, которой не существует. Как задеплоить на Cloudflare Pages, нужна помощь!

Прилагаю лог файл:

```
19:56:05.156    Initializing build environment. This may take up to a few minutes to complete
19:58:51.206    Success: Finished initializing build environment
19:58:51.206    Cloning repository...
19:58:54.513    Success: Finished cloning repository files
19:58:55.515    Installing dependencies
19:58:55.518    Python version set to 2.7
19:58:56.425    v12.18.0 is already installed.
19:58:56.912    Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
19:58:56.953    Started restoring cached build plugins
19:58:56.957    Finished restoring cached build plugins
19:58:57.083    Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
19:58:58.083    Using ruby version 2.7.1
19:58:58.360    Using PHP version 5.6
19:58:58.391    5.2 is already installed.
19:58:58.398    Using Swift version 5.2
19:58:58.398    Started restoring cached node modules
19:58:58.401    Finished restoring cached node modules
19:58:58.403    Started restoring cached yarn cache
19:58:58.406    Finished restoring cached yarn cache
19:58:58.409    Installing yarn at version 1.22.4
19:58:58.412    [37mInstalling Yarn![0m
19:58:58.413    [36m> Downloading tarball...[0m
19:58:58.422    
19:58:58.422    [1/2]: https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.22.4/yarn-v1.22.4.tar.gz --> /tmp/yarn.tar.gz.BpiO1Xhq3T
19:58:58.422      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
19:58:58.422                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
19:58:58.517    
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    79  100    79    0     0    827      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   831
19:58:58.633    
100    93  100    93    0     0    440      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   440
19:58:58.801    
100   656  100   656    0     0   1728      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1728
19:58:58.957    
100 1215k  100 1215k    0     0  2271k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2271k
19:58:58.958    
19:58:58.958    [2/2]: https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.22.4/yarn-v1.22.4.tar.gz.asc --> /tmp/yarn.tar.gz.BpiO1Xhq3T.asc
19:58:58.975    
100    83  100    83    0     0   4741      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4741
19:58:58.983    
100    97  100    97    0     0   3800      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3800
19:58:59.047    
100   660  100   660    0     0   7333      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7333
19:58:59.085    
100  1028  100  1028    0     0   8063      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8063
19:58:59.117    [36m> Verifying integrity...[0m
19:58:59.145    gpg: Signature made Mon 09 Mar 2020 03:52:13 PM UTC using RSA key ID 69475BAA
19:58:59.151    gpg: Good signature from "Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>"
19:58:59.154    gpg: Note: This key has expired!
19:58:59.154    Primary key fingerprint: 72EC F46A 56B4 AD39 C907  BBB7 1646 B01B 86E5 0310
19:58:59.154         Subkey fingerprint: 6D98 490C 6F1A CDDD 448E  4595 4F77 6793 6947 5BAA
19:58:59.155    [32m> GPG signature looks good[0m
19:58:59.155    [36m> Extracting to ~/.yarn...[0m
19:58:59.202    [36m> Adding to $PATH...[0m
19:58:59.206    [36m> We've added the following to your /opt/buildhome/.bashrc
19:58:59.207    > If this isn't the profile of your current shell then please add the following to your correct profile:
19:58:59.207       
19:58:59.207    export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
19:58:59.207    [0m
19:58:59.496    [32m> Successfully installed Yarn 1.22.4! Please open another terminal where the `yarn` command will now be available.[0m
19:58:59.776    Installing NPM modules using Yarn version 1.22.4
19:59:00.231    yarn install v1.22.4
19:59:00.336    warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
19:59:00.341    [1/4] Resolving packages...
19:59:00.647    [2/4] Fetching packages...
19:59:09.863    error globby@12.0.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^12.20.0 || ^14.13.1 || >=16.0.0". Got "12.18.0"
19:59:09.874    error Found incompatible module.
19:59:09.874    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
19:59:09.890    Error during Yarn install
19:59:09.892    Failed: build command exited with code: 1
```

Comment: Так вам надо году обновить, а не globby.

Comment: А если ноду нельзя обновить, то наоборот взять более старую версию globby которая работает со старой нодой

Comment: да, уже разобрался, в cloudflare pages есть возможность выбирать более свежую версию Ноды, теперь все работает!

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил. В Cloudflare Pages в настройках можно указать версию Ноды. Поставил последнюю версию и теперь все работает.